# With jQuery, can you add an HTML element like this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm doing this tutorial and this guy says, "I'm going to create a div..."

```
$("document").ready(function() {
  // fetch the AJAX content
  $("#newsContent").load("news.txt");
  //$.getJSON("news.json", successFn);
});

function successFn(result) {
  $.each(result.newsStories, function(i, item) {
    // Didn't quite understand what this line did.
    var newsDiv = $("<div class='news'>");
    newsDiv.append(item.title);
    newsDiv.append(item.content);
    // Now understand that this puts the above div in play.
    $("#newsContent").append(newsDiv);
  });
}
```

I'm really only worried about this line:

```
var newsDiv = $('<div class="news">');
```

I've tried this on jsfiddle, but it doesn't seem to work. This is happening during the construction of an AJAX request if that helps.

My question is, when does newsDiv become part of the DOM?

Comment: _Am I missing something?_ YES, [mcve]

Comment: Need more description as @Tushar stated

Comment: The snippet you posted is invalid, `.each` cannot start a statement, where's your fiddle? But yes, `var newsDiv = $('<div class="news">');` does create a div in memory

Comment: I'll put the whole thing in a sec.

Comment: @JuanMendes Great! So it puts the div in memory, then when it gets appended it becomes a part of the DOM amirite?

Comment: Yes, it is not appended to the DOM, you have to insert it wherever you'd like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('<div class="news">');` will return $ wrapped object corresponds to an html element (in this example, `div` element) to you. But not created any element at your html. You can simply add this newly created element to your html like,

```
$('#myNewsContainer').append(newsDiv); // append to the div with id 'myNewsContainer'
$('#myNewsContainer').html(newsDiv); // replace all html with new div
```

Comment: __$('<div class="news">'); will NOT return an html element__ It will return `$` wrapped `Object`..

Comment: Bingo. This is what I needed to know. I guess I should have put the rest of the code.

Comment: @RayonDabre, Thanks to correct me :). I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
var newsDiv = $('<div class="news">');
```

creates a variable `newsDiv` with value `<div class="news">`. At this moment it is not appended to html. You can append it to HTML using [Jquery append()](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_append.asp) method.